# Can I use a string as key in mongodb for search?

Tags: mongodb

I am moving my first steps in nosqldb and Mongo, I very much like it, and I have a question about indexes:

In traditional mysql DBs, we usually find a record in a table from the id, that is usually a primary key.

Now in Mongo I can save a lot of different information in text format, and we know is very fast in search for strings, so let's say I am working on a CMS with a lot of records, like several millions, and each document has a url, do you think is a good idea to pull the document using that, rather then an id? I know sound weird but I have my good reasons to do that, unless this is particularly slow.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Indexes](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/indexes/) - Indexes support the efficient execution of queries in MongoDB. [Create an Index](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/method/db.collection.createIndex/) on the appropriate field which would be used in search and retrieve the documents in a faster fashion.

[Text Index](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/core/index-text/) - MongoDB provides text indexes to support text search queries on string content. text indexes can include any field whose value is a string or an array of string elements.

Reference:

https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/full-text-search-in-mongodb--cms-24835

Comment: It seems to me that he doesn't need FTS yet. Just a regular index.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev - Added Index related info as well.

Answer (score 1):

> Can I use a string as key in mongodb for search?

Absolutely. Just don't forget to index it.

If you index the url field, it will be fast. If you don't, it will be slow. Same as all other databases.